# Is it possible to make the tour more prominent to new users again?

Tags: feature-request, new-users, tour

The [tour](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) (redirects to the Chemistry SE tour), is something that gives users a brief idea on how the specific site works. However, this feature has become so hidden away that new users do not even find it until they go into a very specific part of the dashboard or check their profile for the first time.

An example of this can be seen here (using Computer Science SE as an example for a boilerplate standard).

> [image]

Nowhere is the tour even mentioned within the whole page given above. If one wishes to access it, they need to either to go to their profile or need to access the following

> [image]

New users who come in, do neither. They just click on the Ask Question button and see the first image.

Can this tour be made more accessible? Maybe redirect people who don't have the informed badge to the tour page on their first interaction with a stack site?

Comment: The "?" icon is quite clearly "Click here if you need help", and the Tour is right there, first item. This is very obvious, for anyone, new or old time users. Pushing links to Tour elsewhere will just create noise to the old time users and push them away from the site. Bad idea.

Comment: The problem here is that people don't notice this, especially when new users come in. It is not very obvious considering the number of new members ask questions yet don't have the badge. For old time users, they already have the badge and so pass the check that redirects them. If one were an old time user on one stack and move to a new one, won't the tour page give them an idea of what is allowed?

Comment: Someone who will miss and/or ignore a question mark icon floating on top of every page will also miss and/or ignore anything else, even huge blinking red text **CLICK HERE FOR A TOUR** on the whole screen.

Comment: My idea was the following, 'if(logged in), check if(informed) redirect "<correct-place>". else redirect = "/tour" '. The end of the tour has similar redirects too, by which point the badge is awarder

Comment: What is or isn't obvious is theoretical. That is what [usability testing](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) is for (how software is *actually* used in real life).